Why won't the parameters match?
I have this method:
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';

export const getAccessTokenFromCookies = (
  req?: NonNullable<Parameters<typeof getCookie>[1]>['req'],
  res?: NonNullable<Parameters<typeof getCookie>[1]>['res'],
): string | undefined => {
  const session = getCookie(sessionKey, { req, res }); // type errors for req and res
  if (session) {
    const parsedSession = JSON.parse(session);
    return typeof parsedSession === 'object' && parsedSession != null ? parsedSession[accessTokenKey] : undefined;
  } else return undefined;
};

and I get these type errors:

You can see the types of getCookie here: so, <Parameters<typeof getCookie>[1]> is of type OptionsType | undefined, with type OptionsType = DefaultOptions | AppRouterOptions.
The compiler complaint is more or less that DefaultOptions (with has the property req?: IncomingMessage & { cookies?: TmpCookiesObj }) is not of type AppRouterOptions (which has the property res?: Response | NextResponse).
But since I'm deriving the types directly from the expected parameters of getCookie, how could that be? And how could I fix that?
Edit: declaring options?: NonNullable<Parameters<typeof getCookie>[1]> and passing that one to getCookies would work, though.

You're applying a property to the cookies key, which doesn't match with the Request or NextRequest property at that same key. You can either remove that object that declares cookie, extend it to include NextResonse['cookies'] and Response['cookies'], or wrap Request and/or NextRequest with Omit<NextRequest, "cookies">

Thanks for your response! But why is the cookies property I'm applying not a type union of both types of cookie properties? I mean, the options argument at getCookies is fine with any OptionType, and therefore cookies of type TmpCookiesObj are accepted as well as cookies of type (Next.js) RequestCookies etc.

I think you might be going a bit too far backwards to match with the cookies-next library. I've never used it, so I can't give you too many details about my own experience with that specifically, but by defining the req and res properties to match what they will be passed into, you might be causing conflicts with the type that's inferred from wherever that getAccessTokenFromCookies function is called. It's much more ideal to type those properties from where they came from, and then adjust them to fit where they're going, instead of the other way around.

Well, I'm using getAccessTokenFromCookies at places where I have a fetch API Request (in a Next.js route handler) as well at places where I have a NextApiRequest (in Next.js API endpoints). So I felt it appropriate to make this method more a thin layer around getCookies and support the full extend of it's compatibility. But sure, If this won't work type-wise, I'll have to adopt. I just can't wrap my head around what's actually the problem for TypeScript here.

I think the best workaround is to declare the parameters as options?: NonNullable<Parameters<typeof getCookie>[1]> and pass those. I'm still a bit startled that I'm not allowed to pass-through req and res directly (or picking them from options).
